# jQuery popup dialog opening reloads another dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

After Ajax request I write the result in `myDialog` and open the dialog. When closing `myDialog` a `waitDialog` is shown. But after update to jQuery 1.9.1 now the contents of the `myDialog` are reloaded when opening `waitDialog`, looks like Ajax is called one more time. Why? (If I try to insert breakpoint in ajax, it does not stop for the second time.
The reloading happens also if `myDialog` is opened and I call `$("#waitDialog").dialog("open");` from console.
Problem is in Chrome and IE and not in FF.

```
   function myFunction(myId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: myURL,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { id: myId
            },
            success: function (result) {

                $("#myDialog").html(result);

                $("#myDialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Close': function () {
                            showWaitDialog();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });

                $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
            }
        });
    }

    function showWaitDialog() {
         $("#waitDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "wait!"
        });
        $("#waitDialog").parent().css('z-index', '999999');

        $("#waitDialog").dialog("open");

        $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
    }
```

Comment: U are not closing `myDialog` after `close` button clicked

Comment: I copied the main code only and omitted that line. Anyway it does not affect the problem.